# DrawGlyphRun with Style Simulations?

Tags: uwp, win2d

I am working on a UWP app using Win2D and I need very fine control over the layout of the text so I am using DrawGlyphRun. I don't see any way to make DrawGlyphRun use simulated italic and/or bold, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Could you share some code about what you have done now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got this working with the help of the Win2D team, had to drop down into C++ and do the following:

```
CanvasFontFace^ FontHelper::GetFontFaceWithSimulations(CanvasFontFace^ baseFont,
    CanvasFontSimulations simulations)
{
    ComPtr<IDWriteFontFaceReference> nativeSrc = GetWrappedResource<IDWriteFontFaceReference>(baseFont);

    DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS flags = (DWRITE_FONT_SIMULATIONS)simulations;

    ComPtr<IDWriteFontFace3> withSimulations;
    nativeSrc->CreateFontFaceWithSimulations(flags, &withSimulations);

    ComPtr<IDWriteFontFaceReference> nativeResult;
    withSimulations->GetFontFaceReference(&nativeResult);

    CanvasFontFace^ win2dResult = GetOrCreate<CanvasFontFace>(nativeResult.Get());
    return win2dResult;
}
```